# Сборка статического Qt/QML приложения для Linux

Tags: linux, qt, distribution

Цель в том, чтобы создать максимально переносимый и универсальный бинарник. В 2016 я уже делал это с Qt/QtWidgets приложением на версии Qt 5.7, но с тех пор многое изменилось.

Если вдруг в своих рассуждениях или действиях я сотворю глупость, пожалуйста не стесняйтесь мне об этом говорить.

**Как пробовал собирать:**

Собирал для x86_64 на дистрибутиве Ubuntu 20.04 amd64 все библиотеки и компиляторы стоковые из этого дистра. Я посчитал, что других архитектур на десктопах, кроме x86_64 в современном мире не бывает, по этому отказался от сборки x86 версии как я это делал в 2016 (хотя имхо и тогда это была сомнительная затея). Убунту выбрал потому, что как мне казалось, это самый ходовой дистрибутив и в нём-то уж точно "всё как у всех" и не будет никаких подводных камней (как же я ошибался). Итак:

```
arch x86_64
Ubuntu 20.04
gcc/g++ 9.3.0
glibc 2.31
Qt 5.15.2
```

Библиотеки:

```
libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libdrm-dev libxdamage-dev libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa libxext6 libxxf86vm-dev libc6-dev libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxrender-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render-util0-dev libxcb-util-dev libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev libpulse-dev libasound2-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libwayland-dev
```

Конфигурация:

```
./configure -static -platform linux-g++ -prefix "/home/user/Qt/5.15.2/Static" -release -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake tools -opengl desktop -skip wayland -skip qtwebengine -ltcg -optimize-size -no-pch -plugin-sql-sqlite -make libs -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -fontconfig -system-freetype -bundled-xcb-xinput -openssl-linked OPENSSL_INCDIR="/usr/include/openssl"
```

В итоге получился вот такой конфиг, который успешно собрался и успешно собрал моё приложение: https://pastebin.com/4TvNdczx

Примечания:

1. gstreamer (для qt multimedia) не собирается без заголовков wayland, но я посчитал этот wayland какой-то избыточной, никому не нужной экзотикой и исключил его поддержку из Qt (-skip wayland). Если не прав, то поправьте.
2. Из последних версий Qt выкинули поддержку своего XCB (-qt-xcb) со всеми бебехами и завезли какой-то модный -bundled-xcb-xinput. Но как выяснилось он некорректно собирает библиотеку libxcb-xinerama0. Мой бинарник получился динамически линкован с этой библиотекой. Что я только не пробовал, добавлял в .pro SLIBS += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xinerama.a, инклудил xcb/xinerama.h в коде, но линковать эту библиотеку статически не удаётся, а в убунте она по умолчанию не установлена в системе. Хотел выкинуть к чертям эту либу, но флаг конфигурации -no-xinerama, канул в лету вместе с -qt-xcb. К слову сказать, стоковый QtCreator тоже динамически линкован с этой библиотекой.

**Грабли, на которые наступил (три вопроса):**

1. libxcb-xinerama0 (см. примечание 2 к предыдущей части). Вопрос в том, как полностью выкинуть поддержку этой ксинерамы или собрать её статикой.
2. glibc. Я очень удивился, когда загуглив мейнстримные дистрибутивы 2020 (elementaryos, manjaro, openSUSE, kali-linux) и попробовав запустить свой получившийся бинарник, осознал, что он ВООБЩЕ НИГДЕ (!!!) не работает, кроме убунты 20.04 и 20.10. А не работает из-за того, что во всех этих дистрибутивах версии glibc ниже 2.31 (спасибо б...лин Марк ШаттлВрот за моё счастливое детство, простите за эмоцианальность). Вопрос в том, на какой версии glibc лучше собирать Qt и приложение в современных реалиях, чтобы всё везде работало? И как эту версию glibc прикрутить к убунте 20.04 или может выбрать другой дистрибутив? Какой?
3. Анимации и общая производительность UI. В приложении есть анимации, как на базе Animation QML Type, так и на QPropertyAnimation в QtWidgets based коде. Когда собирал бинарник для Windows, наступил на это https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43811. Суть в том, что все анимации в приложении выполняются в несколько раз быстрее чем нужно. Лечится это QSG_RENDER_LOOP=basic https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html. Эта проблема есть на Windows и Linux, она вероятно связана как раз с QSGRendererInterface::OpenGL. Вот как сделан обходной маневр (костыль) у меня:

main.cpp:

```
...
#if defined (Q_OS_WINDOWS)
    QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::OpenGL);
    qputenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP", "basic");
#elif defined (Q_OS_MACOS)
    QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::MetalRhi);
#elif defined (Q_OS_LINUX)
    QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::OpenGL);
    qputenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP", "basic");
#endif
...
```

Проблема тут в том, что при QSG_RENDER_LOOP=basic, весь интерфейс становится чуть дёрганным и подлагивающим. Причем на винде это не так заметно и явно как в Linux. Оно и понятно, все же теперь выполняется в одном треде (если я правильно понимаю). Может кто поборол это, как решить проблему правильно?

**UPD:**
По третьему пункту достиг промежуточных результатов. Вот с такими настройками рендеринга в Linux производительность static сборки значительно лучше:

```
#if defined (Q_OS_WINDOWS)
    QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::OpenGL);
    qputenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP", "basic");
#elif defined (Q_OS_MACOS)
    QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::MetalRhi);
#elif defined (Q_OS_LINUX)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);
    QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::Software);
    qputenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP", "threaded");
#endif
```

Также пересобрал Qt в Ubuntu 18.04 с glibc 2.27 и всеми либами на два года старше. Приложение стало куда более переносимым и завелось во всех вышеперечисленных дистрах. Но увы, иксовый зоопарк библиотек, включая libxcb-xinerama0, линкуется динамически.

Comment: Кажется, для этого хитрые люди придумали docker

Comment: @gbg О чём это вы? Вы предлагаете мне готовый контейнер, в котором есть статическая сборка Qt 5.15.2 в которой нет проблемы со статической линковкой библиотеки libxcb-xinerama0 и проблем с duration анимаций? Если так, то не вижу ссылки.

Comment: Я о том, что есть стандартные пути решения таких проблем - чтобы приложение работало на любом линуксе и таскало за собой все библиотеки, в современных условиях, его проще поместить в docker (и пробросить в докер иксы), чем пытаться собрать статический бинарник. 
Ссылки на контейнер у меня готовой нету - я бы взял ту же убунту, доставил бы в нее недостающие пакеты для графики и прокинул сокет X0.

Comment: И как вы представляете дистрибуцию приложения, помещённого в докер контейнер? Мне в Mac App Store, Microsoft Store и Snap Store докер заливать?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а зачем вам линуксовую версию приложения заливать в Appstore?

Comment: Её надо в Snap Store. Для того, чтобы пользователям было удобно её скачать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119763/discussion-between-gbg-and-posix).

Comment: А не проще использовать шаред линковку и положить дллки в пакет?

Comment: Нет, динамическая линковка даже не рассматривается. Приложение обновляет само себя в виде единственного бинарника, это основа архитектуры автообновлений.